# python rotating file handler callback

Tags: python, logging, file-handling

I'm using the RotatingFileHandler (https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.handlers.html) in Python to log messages - is there anyway to do a function callback when the RotatingFileHandler switches to a new file?

For example, I'm logging messages, and when the file rotates I want to process all of the messages using another defined function

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's not really a callback, but you can easily subclass the RotatingFileHandler and override your own "rotation", by implementing the [doRollover method](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.handlers.html#logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler.doRollover):

```
MyFileHandler(RotatingFileHandler):

    def doRollover():
        # invoke the superclass' actual rotation implementation
        super(MyFileHandler, self).doRollover()

        # start doing your own tasks
        # ...
```

Comment: that's a great solution! is there a way to get the file handle for the last closed file after the rollover?

Comment: I'm pretty sure - though I don't really know the details of the RotatingFileHandler implementation. Have a look at the actual implementation: https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/23ab1197df0b/Lib/logging/handlers.py#l117 that may help...